# get node creation date in a view

Tags: views, polls

I'm trying to get a nodes "poll" created date and how much time it has until it closes in a view.
but having a problem reaching that information for the available fields, I tried to create a relation with the content: author with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poll is a core module and it appears that it doesn't make the "end date" available to views. You could add your own "end date" field to the poll content type but then you have to enter it twice.

Or try the more advanced [pollfield](http://drupal.org/project/pollfield) module:

```
Because pollfield allows you to build polls as part of the CCK system, this module provides a more flexible polling option than the Drupal core poll module.
```

Please let me know how it goes, I'm interested in the pollfield module myself, just don't have time right now to play with it ;-)

Comment: I didnt get the chance to play around with the pollfield module, but looks like it would work. about the issue, the whole project got dropped so, no further work will be done. accepted answer :)